# PHP not returning value to jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to create a gif to show while php works on the query, what I did was this:

```
var loader = $('#loader');
$(function() {
     $('form').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefaults();
          loader.show();
          $.ajax({
               url: 'php.php',
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               method: 'post',
               dataType: 'JSON'
          }).done(function(valueBack) {
               loader.hide();
               alert(valueBack);
          });
     });
});
```

the php code is just

```
json_encode(array('valueBack' => 'a'));
```

but I dont get any alert and the animation of the loader keeps playing

Comment: Probably an internal error, check the console.

Comment: show the php code? Have you tried using the javascript debugger built into your web browser? does that .done() callback never get hit?

Comment: check your browser console and see what error is there.Also share your php code too.

Comment: Isn't `e.preventDefaults()` a typo?

Comment: have a .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); } ) on the ajax call so you can take a look at the error.